# How to do Scrolling Lyrics with animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, core-animation, avaudioplayer

In my app, I want to add scrolling lyrics, like `UIPickerView` rolling lyrics, according to the song. I tried Cloud Label In Code4App (http://code4app.net/ios/Tab-cloud/5235d23f6803fa2f7b000000) but I'm not understanding that code since I'm new to Obj-C!

[image]

Can anyone please help me or suggest tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to be able to use a `UIPickerView` for what you're describing since I don't think there's any way to do a slow controlled scroll on a `UIPickerView`, especially while changing the text characteristics continuously.

I think you might be better off using a `UITableView`, animating the content offset to scroll, and using attributed text to change the highlights.

I don't know how to get that circular `UIPickerView` "look" you're trying to achieve though. That might be more complicated...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Lyndsey that a picker view is not the right tool for what you are trying to do.

If you are a beginner at Objective C this is probably over your head. Way, way over your head even.

You would need to use Core Animation on the layers of a set of text views, and rotate those views around the Y axis, with the center of rotation being behind the view. You'd need to manipulate the transformation matrixes that you apply to each layer to get a perspective effect (applying a value of around -1/500.0 to the m34 entry in the CATransform3D)

For now I would suggest giving up on 3D rolling perspective, and just using UIView animation (look at the method `animateWithDuration:animations:` and it's cousins. That's nice and easy to use.

Comment: I am not using UIPickerView.but animate lyrics like uiPickerView Style.You know how to animate the label and change the text color like above image

Comment: Handling the text color is a whole different problem One thing at a time.

Comment: Yes, I could develop an animation that rolls the text the way you describe, but it would be involved and probably take several hours for me to develop. That's more work than I'm prepared to do for free.